# Android - How to Resize/Reposition ImageView According to Parent?

Tags: java, c#, android

What's the recommended approach for ensuring an ImageView button is the correct size according to its parent?

I have a VideoView set to "match_parent" (screen width) and an ImageView over the VideoView that is 60dp x 60dp, which is fine on the screen I'm testing.

Problem is, if I rotate the phone and the VideoView is much smaller, the ImageView is no longer proportional and in the correct position. Same issue is true for larger screen sizes such as tablets.

I want the ImageView to always be the same proportional size and appear in the same position relative to the VideoView (its parent).

Comment: Why have you tagged C# ? Is that a Xamarin related question ?

Comment: @VadimCaen I'm using Xamarin, but the question isn't really language specific. I'm asking for a general technique, not necessarily specific code.

Comment: Did you take a look at the new ConstraintLayout ? It might be what you need (even if there is other solution). It would be great if you can show be a drawing of what you try to achieve.

Comment: You need Android Studio 2.2 from the canary channel though

Comment: @VadimCaen I don't think ConstraintLayout is available for Xamarin.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about you using Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using layout_sum in android:

Since I don't know how you are exactly coding this, I can only provide assumptions based code. I am assuming that you would want to proportionately align an VideoView and ImageView in a parent. (Assuming you required 30% of the space to be occupied by the ImageView and the rest 70% of the space to be occupied by the VideoView).

You can code the XML file as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="10"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_gravity="center">

<VideoView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="3"/>

<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="7"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will embed the VideoView and ImageView into the LinearLayout (Parent view).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RelativeLayout,wrapContent and avoid using hardCoded sizes.

Or better define a separate layout for Landscape and Portrait View that may solve your issue.

Even if your issue is not solved try using this library i frequently use it in my projects-[SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: For a simple problem like that, it would be better to avoid the overhead of a library.

Comment: Yes I know...was just hinting about such a library which can ease our job for making layout compatible to different screens.

Comment: As I said in my comment to aditya, ConstraintLayout is a new layout that can handle this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. I didn't knew.Started reading about it already.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this programmatically using ViewTreeObserver GlobalLayout listener. It works great and I only need it for one view on the screen, so not a big deal. Button appears in the correct position relative to its parent size even with the phone is rotated.

```
    var topPadding = Convert.ToInt32(_videoView.Height * .25);
    _buttonLayout.SetPadding(_buttonLayout.PaddingLeft, topPadding, _buttonLayout.PaddingRight, _buttonLayout.PaddingBottom);
```